# Joomla Article: Edit in standard mode

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I am using joomla 1.5.I wanted to add some youtube link to the article so i switched to no editor mode and made changes that worked for me.when i turned back to TinyMCE it still shows articles in HTML mode for all articles in the article manager.how do i switch back to earlier no Html simple text edit mode???

Answer (score 0):

problem solved: I disabled No Editor from plugin manager. Now its switched to default editor

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to upgrade your joomla version as joomla 1.5 has no support and security updates.

Answer (score 0):

download component JCE Editor . install it and make it default 
it should fix your problem and it's much more better than tynyMce

http://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/downloads/editor/joomla15x